# getting gps position after taking photo

Tags: android, gps

I tried to get the gps position when i taking a photo. i saved the position of the location-listener when the LocationChanged method is running in a variable and want to show it when i take a photo. Is this the right way? I use android 2.3.6.
Here my code:

```
    package com.exercise;



import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;

public class AndroidCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean previewing = false;
    LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;

    Button buttonTakePicture;

    final int RESULT_SAVEIMAGE = 0;

    public Location test;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
        LayoutParams layoutParamsControl 
            = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

        buttonTakePicture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
        buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, 
                        myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);
            }});

        LinearLayout layoutBackground = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.background);
        layoutBackground.setOnClickListener(new LinearLayout.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                buttonTakePicture.setEnabled(false);
                camera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
            }});
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        @Override

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();
            String Text = "Lat = " + loc.getLatitude() + "|Long = " + loc.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //  final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
          //  tv.setText(tv.getText()+ "||" + Text);
            test = loc;
        }

        @Override

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }

        @Override

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
        }

    }

    AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buttonTakePicture.setEnabled(true);
        }};

    ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }};

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }};

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*Bitmap bitmapPicture 
                = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);  */

            Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());

            OutputStream imageFileOS;
            try {
                imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
                imageFileOS.write(arg0);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();

//              Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, 
//                      "Image saved: " + uriTarget.toString(), 
//                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//              test.getLatitude();
//              test.getLongitude();
//              String Text = "Lat = " + test.getLatitude() + "|Long = " + test.getLongitude();
//              Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (test==null){
                    Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    test.getLatitude();
                    String ausgabe = String.valueOf(test.getLatitude());
                    Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, ausgabe, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            camera.startPreview();
        }};

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(previewing){
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }

        if (camera != null){
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera = Camera.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        previewing = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a fair way to do it.  By the way, you can instead .requestSingleUpdate(), since you'll be wanting only one update.  You should also probably not wait until the GPS information arrives (and, you can also specify something different than a gps provider, like, any provider, which may respond quicker -- as opposed to a possible cold start from GPS).  If none of that works, you can always query for the last known location.  Since the update may not arrive for a while, you should probably save the image data somewhere lazily (without location information), and then update the information when location becomes available.

Comment: but how can i get the position at the moment of the photo, how can i activate the search for a position?

Comment: You can't.  If the GPS starts, it might take a while for it to warm up and get a fix on the location.  If it doesn't already have a fix, there's no possible way to know where you are before starting it.  Instead, when you take a picture, you start and request an update, and then a few seconds / minutes later, hopefully you get a fix on the location.  There's no magic way to get a location instantly.